# Настройка cmake для сборки С/С++ кода под Андроид

Tags: cmake, android, android-ndk, c, c++

Я занимаюсь портом приложения под андроид. Наш проект написан на C и строится с помощью cmake. Подскажите, кто сталкивался, как настроить cmake для того, чтобы собрать с его помощью С/С++ код для андроида?

Answer (score 7):

Берёшь и используешь по инструкции внутри файла.
[OpenCV android cmake toolchain](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/android/android.toolchain.cmake)

Comment: @ganelon, справа под вопросом есть **дата**, когда он был задан.

Серьезно считаете, что ответы все еще актуальны для TC?

Comment: @avp, это ж разминка )) @ganelon только зарегистрировался, вот и разминается. ;)

Comment: @Deonis, это я понял, вот и подсказал чуток. 

@ganelon, ждем других Ваших ответов.

Comment: Ну мало ли кому нибудь будет полезно. Мне пригодилось. ;)

Comment: @avp: Если я правильно понимаю суть ХК (и если он продолжает идеи SO), то он не только решалка вопросов, но и база знаний, где ответы не поздно добавлять и редактировать ни через год, ни через два, ни через десять.

Так что @ganelon все правильно делает. А вот с чего тут есть закрытие с «проблема не ауктуальна» — вот это, как раз, непонятно. Но это надо идти на мету (а мне лень).

Comment: @drdaemon, похоже Вы правы, насчет базы знаний. Поэтому переоткрыл вопрос. 

Пусть еще послужит полигоном для новобранцев.

Comment: Ога, понекропощу немного тоже :) предлагаю админам скорректировать ссылку на: https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake и добавить сылку на старший SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343797/building-a-toolchain-with-cmake-to-cross-compile-for-android